# unable to get json_decode field

Tags: php, json

I want to get title for each song from the json below in php.I am unable to get all the names .I tried with the code below but its not displaying anything.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=5/json'); 
$data=(json_decode($json, true));

foreach ($data as $item)
{
    foreach ($item->entry as $asset)
    {
        echo $asset->title;
    }

}
```

json:

```
    {
  "feed": {
    "author": {
      "name": {
        "label": "iTunes Store"
      },
      "uri": {
        "label": "http://www.apple.com/itunes/"
      }
    },
    "entry": [
      {
        "im:name": {
          "label": "Happy (From \"Despicable Me 2\")"
        },
        "im:image": [
          {
            "label": "http://a923.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music6/v4/7b/9c/58/7b9c58cb-71b8-44f1-5539-864ea5e505e2/886444495165.55x55-70.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "55"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a1645.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music6/v4/7b/9c/58/7b9c58cb-71b8-44f1-5539-864ea5e505e2/886444495165.60x60-50.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "60"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a1228.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music6/v4/7b/9c/58/7b9c58cb-71b8-44f1-5539-864ea5e505e2/886444495165.170x170-75.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "170"
            }
          }
        ],
        "im:collection": {
          "im:name": {
            "label": "G I R L"
          },
          "link": {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/g-i-r-l/id823593445?uo=2"
            }
          },
          "im:contentType": {
            "im:contentType": {
              "attributes": {
                "term": "Album",
                "label": "Album"
              }
            },
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Music",
              "label": "Music"
            }
          }
        },
        "im:price": {
          "label": "$1.29",
          "attributes": {
            "amount": "1.29000",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        "im:contentType": {
          "im:contentType": {
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Track",
              "label": "Track"
            }
          },
          "attributes": {
            "term": "Music",
            "label": "Music"
          }
        },
        "rights": {
          "label": "℗ 2014 Columbia Records, a Division of Sony Music Entertainment, 2013 Back Lot Music, under exclusive license to Columbia Records, a Division of Sony Music Entertainment"
        },
        "title": {
          "label": "Happy (From \"Despicable Me 2\") - Pharrell Williams"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/happy-from-despicable-me-2/id823593445?i=823593456&uo=2"
            }
          },
          {
            "im:duration": {
              "label": "30000"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Preview",
              "rel": "enclosure",
              "type": "audio/x-m4a",
              "href": "http://a1083.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/014/Music/v4/4e/44/b7/4e44b7dc-aaa2-c63b-fb38-88e1635b5b29/mzaf_1844128138535731917.plus.aac.p.m4a",
              "im:assetType": "preview"
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": {
          "label": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/happy-from-despicable-me-2/id823593445?i=823593456&uo=2",
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "823593456"
          }
        },
        "im:artist": {
          "label": "Pharrell Williams",
          "attributes": {
            "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/pharrell-williams/id14934728?uo=2"
          }
        },
        "category": {
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "14",
            "term": "Pop",
            "scheme": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/music-pop/id14?uo=2",
            "label": "Pop"
          }
        },
        "im:releaseDate": {
          "label": "2014-03-03T00:00:00-07:00",
          "attributes": {
            "label": "March 3, 2014"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "im:name": {
          "label": "All of Me"
        },
        "im:image": [
          {
            "label": "http://a1221.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Features/v4/c6/16/d4/c616d4bc-ae3c-2c3a-9b48-7ffece9e29b3/dj.velovadm.55x55-70.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "55"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a1943.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Features/v4/c6/16/d4/c616d4bc-ae3c-2c3a-9b48-7ffece9e29b3/dj.velovadm.60x60-50.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "60"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a982.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Features/v4/c6/16/d4/c616d4bc-ae3c-2c3a-9b48-7ffece9e29b3/dj.velovadm.170x170-75.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "170"
            }
          }
        ],
        "im:collection": {
          "im:name": {
            "label": "Love in the Future (Deluxe Edition)"
          },
          "link": {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/love-in-future-deluxe-edition/id679297685?uo=2"
            }
          },
          "im:contentType": {
            "im:contentType": {
              "attributes": {
                "term": "Album",
                "label": "Album"
              }
            },
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Music",
              "label": "Music"
            }
          }
        },
        "im:price": {
          "label": "$1.29",
          "attributes": {
            "amount": "1.29000",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        "im:contentType": {
          "im:contentType": {
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Track",
              "label": "Track"
            }
          },
          "attributes": {
            "term": "Music",
            "label": "Music"
          }
        },
        "rights": {
          "label": "℗ 2013 Getting Out Our Dreams and Columbia Records, a Division of Sony Music Entertainment"
        },
        "title": {
          "label": "All of Me - John Legend"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/all-of-me/id679297685?i=679297849&uo=2"
            }
          },
          {
            "im:duration": {
              "label": "30000"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Preview",
              "rel": "enclosure",
              "type": "audio/x-m4a",
              "href": "http://a355.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/041/Music4/v4/90/cf/04/90cf0482-07c0-fca0-549f-c1ea62c4bdef/mzaf_6715619947923767616.plus.aac.p.m4a",
              "im:assetType": "preview"
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": {
          "label": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/all-of-me/id679297685?i=679297849&uo=2",
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "679297849"
          }
        },
        "im:artist": {
          "label": "John Legend",
          "attributes": {
            "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/john-legend/id16586443?uo=2"
          }
        },
        "category": {
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "15",
            "term": "R&B/Soul",
            "scheme": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/music-r-b-soul/id15?uo=2",
            "label": "R&B/Soul"
          }
        },
        "im:releaseDate": {
          "label": "2013-08-30T00:00:00-07:00",
          "attributes": {
            "label": "August 30, 2013"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "im:name": {
          "label": "Let It Go"
        },
        "im:image": [
          {
            "label": "http://a261.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/v4/26/be/46/26be4693-e743-f45a-4629-35554af16181/UMG_cvrart_00050087301644_01_RGB72_1500x1500_13DMGIM04438.55x55-70.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "55"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a983.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/v4/26/be/46/26be4693-e743-f45a-4629-35554af16181/UMG_cvrart_00050087301644_01_RGB72_1500x1500_13DMGIM04438.60x60-50.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "60"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a262.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/v4/26/be/46/26be4693-e743-f45a-4629-35554af16181/UMG_cvrart_00050087301644_01_RGB72_1500x1500_13DMGIM04438.170x170-75.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "170"
            }
          }
        ],
        "im:collection": {
          "im:name": {
            "label": "Frozen (Deluxe Edition) [Original Motion Picture Soundtrack]"
          },
          "link": {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/frozen-deluxe-edition-original/id728903889?uo=2"
            }
          },
          "im:contentType": {
            "im:contentType": {
              "attributes": {
                "term": "Album",
                "label": "Album"
              }
            },
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Music",
              "label": "Music"
            }
          }
        },
        "im:price": {
          "label": "$1.29",
          "attributes": {
            "amount": "1.29000",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        "im:contentType": {
          "im:contentType": {
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Track",
              "label": "Track"
            }
          },
          "attributes": {
            "term": "Music",
            "label": "Music"
          }
        },
        "rights": {
          "label": "℗ 2013 Walt Disney Records"
        },
        "title": {
          "label": "Let It Go - Idina Menzel"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/let-it-go/id728903889?i=728904000&uo=2"
            }
          },
          {
            "im:duration": {
              "label": "30000"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Preview",
              "rel": "enclosure",
              "type": "audio/x-m4a",
              "href": "http://a878.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/023/Music/v4/0a/eb/c2/0aebc299-44e3-3465-3cdf-5bab336b547a/mzaf_7970981567593232494.plus.aac.p.m4a",
              "im:assetType": "preview"
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": {
          "label": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/let-it-go/id728903889?i=728904000&uo=2",
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "728904000"
          }
        },
        "im:artist": {
          "label": "Idina Menzel",
          "attributes": {
            "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/idina-menzel/id3297504?uo=2"
          }
        },
        "category": {
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "16",
            "term": "Soundtrack",
            "scheme": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/music-soundtrack/id16?uo=2",
            "label": "Soundtrack"
          }
        },
        "im:releaseDate": {
          "label": "2013-11-25T00:00:00-07:00",
          "attributes": {
            "label": "November 25, 2013"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "im:name": {
          "label": "Dark Horse (feat. Juicy J)"
        },
        "im:image": [
          {
            "label": "http://a1657.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Features4/v4/f7/3e/40/f73e4011-5ed3-fc65-9107-2438acd70509/dj.hbxrueel.55x55-70.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "55"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a731.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Features4/v4/f7/3e/40/f73e4011-5ed3-fc65-9107-2438acd70509/dj.hbxrueel.60x60-50.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "60"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a1498.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Features4/v4/f7/3e/40/f73e4011-5ed3-fc65-9107-2438acd70509/dj.hbxrueel.170x170-75.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "170"
            }
          }
        ],
        "im:collection": {
          "im:name": {
            "label": "PRISM (Deluxe Version)"
          },
          "link": {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/prism-deluxe-version/id690928033?uo=2"
            }
          },
          "im:contentType": {
            "im:contentType": {
              "attributes": {
                "term": "Album",
                "label": "Album"
              }
            },
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Music",
              "label": "Music"
            }
          }
        },
        "im:price": {
          "label": "$1.29",
          "attributes": {
            "amount": "1.29000",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        "im:contentType": {
          "im:contentType": {
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Track",
              "label": "Track"
            }
          },
          "attributes": {
            "term": "Music",
            "label": "Music"
          }
        },
        "rights": {
          "label": "℗ 2013 Capitol Records, LLC"
        },
        "title": {
          "label": "Dark Horse (feat. Juicy J) - Katy Perry"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/dark-horse-feat.-juicy-j/id690928033?i=690928460&uo=2"
            }
          },
          {
            "im:duration": {
              "label": "30000"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Preview",
              "rel": "enclosure",
              "type": "audio/x-m4a",
              "href": "http://a1930.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/022/Music/v4/a4/ac/63/a4ac6341-59e3-bcfe-b7f5-370100eea063/mzaf_4835051646631223146.plus.aac.p.m4a",
              "im:assetType": "preview"
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": {
          "label": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/dark-horse-feat.-juicy-j/id690928033?i=690928460&uo=2",
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "690928460"
          }
        },
        "im:artist": {
          "label": "Katy Perry",
          "attributes": {
            "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/katy-perry/id64387566?uo=2"
          }
        },
        "category": {
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "14",
            "term": "Pop",
            "scheme": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/music-pop/id14?uo=2",
            "label": "Pop"
          }
        },
        "im:releaseDate": {
          "label": "2013-10-22T00:00:00-07:00",
          "attributes": {
            "label": "October 22, 2013"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "im:name": {
          "label": "The Man"
        },
        "im:image": [
          {
            "label": "http://a1169.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music4/v4/67/f0/bb/67f0bbfb-9b0f-ee34-3646-b1bfbe704d4f/UMG_cvrart_00602537732579_01_RGB72_1500x1500_13UAEIM00026.55x55-70.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "55"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a243.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music4/v4/67/f0/bb/67f0bbfb-9b0f-ee34-3646-b1bfbe704d4f/UMG_cvrart_00602537732579_01_RGB72_1500x1500_13UAEIM00026.60x60-50.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "60"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a1234.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music4/v4/67/f0/bb/67f0bbfb-9b0f-ee34-3646-b1bfbe704d4f/UMG_cvrart_00602537732579_01_RGB72_1500x1500_13UAEIM00026.170x170-75.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "170"
            }
          }
        ],
        "im:collection": {
          "im:name": {
            "label": "Lift Your Spirit"
          },
          "link": {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/lift-your-spirit/id798928288?uo=2"
            }
          },
          "im:contentType": {
            "im:contentType": {
              "attributes": {
                "term": "Album",
                "label": "Album"
              }
            },
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Music",
              "label": "Music"
            }
          }
        },
        "im:price": {
          "label": "$1.29",
          "attributes": {
            "amount": "1.29000",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        "im:contentType": {
          "im:contentType": {
            "attributes": {
              "term": "Track",
              "label": "Track"
            }
          },
          "attributes": {
            "term": "Music",
            "label": "Music"
          }
        },
        "rights": {
          "label": "℗ 2014 Aloe Blacc Recording, Inc. under exclusive license to XIX Recordings LLC/Interscope Records"
        },
        "title": {
          "label": "The Man - Aloe Blacc"
        },
        "link": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "rel": "alternate",
              "type": "text/html",
              "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/the-man/id798928288?i=798928362&uo=2"
            }
          },
          {
            "im:duration": {
              "label": "30000"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Preview",
              "rel": "enclosure",
              "type": "audio/x-m4a",
              "href": "http://a85.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/033/Music6/v4/8a/09/dc/8a09dcf0-4845-81ae-6936-a94972ad94e7/mzaf_5332424013433716082.plus.aac.p.m4a",
              "im:assetType": "preview"
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": {
          "label": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/the-man/id798928288?i=798928362&uo=2",
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "798928362"
          }
        },
        "im:artist": {
          "label": "Aloe Blacc",
          "attributes": {
            "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/aloe-blacc/id4750752?uo=2"
          }
        },
        "category": {
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "14",
            "term": "Pop",
            "scheme": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/music-pop/id14?uo=2",
            "label": "Pop"
          }
        },
        "im:releaseDate": {
          "label": "2014-03-11T00:00:00-07:00",
          "attributes": {
            "label": "March 11, 2014"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "updated": {
      "label": "2014-03-26T14:09:41-07:00"
    },
    "rights": {
      "label": "Copyright 2008 Apple Inc."
    },
    "title": {
      "label": "iTunes Store: Top Songs"
    },
    "icon": {
      "label": "http://itunes.apple.com/favicon.ico"
    },
    "link": [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "rel": "alternate",
          "type": "text/html",
          "href": "https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?cc=us&id=38&popId=1"
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=5/json"
        }
      }
    ],
    "id": {
      "label": "http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=5/json"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `json_decode($json, true)` to `json_decode($json)`. If second parameter is set to true the decoded output will be associative array and object otherwise.

Comment: I tried that also its not working.Please try the code above it will not display anything.

Comment: Have you got any errors then? Put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` on the top of your PHP script.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string `echo $asset->title;`

Comment: Basically I need array of all titles.How do I get and store it ?Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I see now. It should be `echo $asset->title->label;`

Comment: I get the values now Thanks .Now How do I add the same to an array as all the titles are stuck to each other and I cannot differentiate .I guess I need to put it in an array.I get  `Happy (From "Despicable Me 2") - Pharrell WilliamsAll of Me - John LegendLet It Go - Idina MenzelDark Horse (feat. Juicy J) - Katy PerryThe Man - Aloe BlaccTalk Dirty (feat. 2 Chainz) - Jason DeruloTurn Down For What - DJ Snake & Lil JonPompeii - Bastille#SELFIE - The ChainsmokersThis Is How We Roll (feat. Luke Bryan) - Florida Georgia Line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=5/json'); 
$data=json_decode($json);

$titles = array();
foreach ($data as $item) 
{
    foreach ($item->entry as $asset) 
    {
        $titles[] = $asset->title->label;
    }
}
```